# Highcharts Pie Chart - Showing Negative value as "null" in legend

Tags: jquery, highcharts, pie-chart

I'm using HighCharts to create a pie chart, but the set of data I'm working with has a negative number. The portion that is negative is so small that it really doesn't matter in the pie chart itself, but I'm having display issues in the legend. I found an older demo that used a older version of highcharts.js that displayed the negative number http://jsfiddle.net/AdW2Z/8/

```
 pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.point.positive ? this.y : this.y * (-1);
            },
            color: 'black',
            style: {
                font: '13px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
```

I tried using the same code, but with the current version of highcharts.js, but that's where I get a "null" in the legend:
http://jsfiddle.net/bRZaw/1/

Any ideas how I can fix this? I've been battling with the the past 3 days. Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original object with data from user could be find in `this.options.y`, so you can always use that value, see: http://jsfiddle.net/bRZaw/9/

Answer (score 1):

Pie charts are supposed to represent a part of a total so it is expected that negative numbers won't work because you can't have a negative part of a total. If you need to represent negative values then you probably should use another type of chart.

In case that you actually want to just show that value (given that you said it isn't really significant over all), try wrapping it in an absolute value, Math.abs(yourValue) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can show 0 for negative numbers in legend by updating `labelFormatter` as below:

```
labelFormatter: function () {
    if (this.y === null) {
        return this.name + ': 0%';
    } else {
        return this.name + ': ' + this.y + '%';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bRZaw/3/